# C++ HashMap or Map in terms of time complexity and memory space

Tags: algorithm, c++11, dictionary, complexity-theory, unordered-map

I've to store a sparse matrix in which the elements are just '1' or '2' (represent BlueCar and RedCar). 
I know the size of the matrix only at runtime after reading a .csv with comma separated values.
I have to implement an **algorithm to move cars**:

- blue ones move *downward*;
- red ones move *rightward*;
- there is a *turn* in which all the blue ones move and a turn to move all the red ones (move of a car can happen only if the destination is empty).

So the algorithm must:

- cycle over the data structure (to select red cars or blue cars to move)
- must find if the destination position is free. Free means '**position
  does not exist**', because I want to save only the existing cars
  associated with their coordinates.
- must update coordinates of moving cars or delete the old position and insert the new one.

**I have to choose the best data structure to save cars and coordinates that is efficient in terms of time complexity and memory usage.**

To be detailed, in the next steps of the implementation I have to deal with openMP and MPI.

It's better to use a single structure with key-value pair **(1)** or one structure per car type **(2)** in which I need only to save coordinates?

**(1)** I thought to a `std::map<std::pair<row,column>,value>` or `std::unordered_map`.
I don't know what to choose, but I know that **map access is O(logN) and unordered is O(1)**. I think that the elements in the unordered map can be easily ordered because I insert them in a ordered way when the file is read.
When the car moves I have to change its coordinates that are the key of the map/unordered_map. But now the question is: it's better the change the key (if it's possible) or to delete and insert a new key-value pair?

**(2)** If in this situation the 2nd case is better for me than the 1st one, which data structure can I implement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, blue car is only move downward, so, you only need a `map< column, set<row>>` to store position of blue car.

Similarly, we can store position of red car as `map< row, set<column>>`

This will reduce the memory usage of your program, and may speed up your look up performance.

The lookup performance for case `map<column, set<row>>` will be better, as we know that the data structure using in map is binary search tree, so, for `map<pair<row, column> , value>`, the size of the tree is much larger than in the former case. Imagine that you need to look up for <2,3>, so, in latter case, you may need to travel through all pair <1,x> until you reach <2,x> and finally the destination.

For `unordered_map`, the performance is also better, as `unordered_map` is using hashing, the approach `pair<row, column>` need to map a much larger number of items to the same space size, compare with just map `row` , so the number of collisions are much larger.

Further more, we know that, it is better to process blue car column by column, then row by row, because, in that case, we can easily detect the case when there is a blue car (1, 1) follow by (2, 1) , which may cause collision, so storing blue car by `unordered_map`, then storing column by order set may bring huge advantage. So, by using this approach, we can easily swap with using map or `unordered_map`, set or `unordered_set` easily, depending on the requirement and performance.

Comment: It is the better to update or to delete/insert a new pair when a car moves? Isn't for the lookup performance `map<std::pair<row,column>,value>` better?

Comment: I upvoted, but a sorted std::vector with the use of std::lower_bound ought to provide better performance than std::map, i.e. std::vector< column, set<row>>. The vector only needs to be sorted once.

Comment: With `unordered_map<col, set<row>>` I can have a lot of collisions, so its performance during lookup are worse than `map<col, set<row>` in this case...right?

Comment: @rh0x not necessary, depending on the hashing algorithm and number of  entry. Ideally, unordered_map will give you O(1) look up performance (perfect hashing), and map will give you O(log n) with n is number of entry. You can perform some kind of benchmark to choose what is the most suitable structure or hashing algorithm for your program.

Comment: *"Ideally, unordered_map will give you O(1) look up performance (perfect hashing)"* - O(1) lookup is to be expected, but you can't expect *perfect hashing* (which means 0 collisions) given arbitrary numeric inputs spread across a range much larger than the bucket count: general-purpose hash tables work well *despite* significant numbers of collisions.